# express res.render send object array in options

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, express, javascript-objects

how can I pass in an object array into res.render options? I've been having trouble with this for some time now, when I only pass in the array I only get [Object][object] and when I try to console log the received array at an index I receive an "undefined" error
Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show the exact code that produces the output you're seeing?

Comment: Sure! the array I use for testing purposes looks something like this : 
`var DataArray = [
    {"type": "c#", "script":"csharp script"},
    {"type": "javascript", "script":"javascript script"},
    {"type": "html", "script":"html script"}
]`
And I call the render like this:
`res.render('index.ejs', {"data":DataArray})`
And in the index.ejs file it looks like this:
`<script>
         var data = '<%= data  %>'; 
         console.log(data[0].type)
  </script>`

Comment: You can not output an object or an array directly in an ejs file because it expects text context - actually anything else will be coerced to a string, which may give unexpected behaviour. `[object Object]` for instance is the default coercion for objects. So make it so to output only string content in your ejs file - or anything else that coerces to a valid string.

Comment: You are using ```var data = '<%= data  %>';``` which is trying to pass escaped value, replace with this ```var data = '<%- data  %>';``` for unescaped value.